# TUXERA POSIX Test Suite: Getting Actual Resultant

Tags: testing, filesystems, posix

I'm running the TUXERA POSIX Test Suite and lets just say, the first run through my FS was a disaster. Anyways, is there an option to display what my FS actually provided as a resultant for each test? Having some more clues of where my FS went wrong would be great.

Let me know. Thanks!